# The request payload is invalid. Ensure to provide a valid request payload

Tags: botframework, bots

After 10 to 15 times of `return await sc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog));`

the error was:

> Errors":["The request payload is invalid. Ensure to provide a valid
>   request payload."]

Scenario:
Use: Enterprise Bot Template

In Main Dialog after Dispatch => QnA Answer Result is asking for feedback using suggestion card [Thumbs Up/Down]

If the user is selecting the Thumbs Up/Down, they are able to end the dialog.
If they do not select any option, the user needs to enter another query that needs to be processed through Maindialog again (DISPATCH => LUIS/QnA).

In my scenario, the user without giving feedback is entering new queries after 10 
 to 15 times is getting a server error.

```
var answers = await qnaService.GetAnswersAsync(dc.Context);

                        if (answers != null && answers.Count() > 0 && answers[0].Score >= _bestQnAScore)
                        {
                            string personalizedAnswer = DialogUtilities.PersonalizeAnswer(answers[0].Answer, _authResult, greetingInQNAAnswerSetting);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(personalizedAnswer))
                            {
                                personalizedAnswer = StringUtils.URLBlankSpaceHelper(personalizedAnswer);
                                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(personalizedAnswer, personalizedAnswer, "acceptingInput");

                                string[] arrQnAMetadata = _configuration["QnAMetadata"].ToString().Split(',');
                                string stringToCheck = (answers[0].Metadata.Length > 0) ? answers[0].Metadata.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToLower() : string.Empty;
                                bool isChitChat = arrQnAMetadata.Any(stringToCheck.Contains);
                                if (!isChitChat)
                                {
                                    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(FeedbackDialog), new VM_Luis_AuthResult(null, _authResult, _EnumDISPATCHIntent.ToString()));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    #region OPEN/CLOSE TICKET
                                    FeedbackLogger.LogUserFeedback(_authResult.UserEmail, dc.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id, dc.Context.Activity.Text, _authResult.Country, _authResult.City, _authResult.OfficeLocation, TicketState.Open, TicketStatus.None, ref this._topScoringIntent, ref this._ticketNumber);
                                    FeedbackLogger.LogUserFeedback(_authResult.UserEmail, dc.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id, dc.Context.Activity.Text, _authResult.Country, _authResult.City, _authResult.OfficeLocation, TicketState.Closed, TicketStatus.Successful, ref this._topScoringIntent, ref this._ticketNumber);
                                    #endregion
                                    await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Confused);
                            await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                        }
```

**FeedbackDialog.cs**

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnFeedbackResult(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var res = Convert.ToString(sc.Result);
            if (InterruptionsConstants.NegativeFeedback.Any(f => res.ToLower() == f))
            {
                await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Thank You!");
                return await sc.EndDialogAsync();
            }
            else if (InterruptionsConstants.PositiveFeedback.Any(f => res.ToLower() == f))
            {
                await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Thank you very much");
                return await sc.EndDialogAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                 return await sc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank You in advance. :)

Comment: else
            {
                 rawait sc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
                return await sc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog));
            }

Comment: Is your issue resolved?